# Getting iframe content with $() (update: In mootools)?

Tags: dom, iframe, mootools

how do i minify this in mootools.

```
window.frames['buffer'].document.body.innerHTML
```

in mootools, this does not work:

```
$('buffer').$('body').get('html');
```

OR

```
$('buffer').get('html')
```

Comment: Are you looking for a mootools solution, or a jQuery solution? Your wording isn't clear.

Comment: I just assumed he wanted either.

Comment: yeah mootools! but i thought jQuery was so similar it wouldnt matter. I wasn't. I have updated the question!

Answer (score 5):

As long as your page and iframe are in the same domain you should be able to use the following:

```
new IFrame('buffer').contentDocument.getElement('body').get('html');
```

Comment: Yes, but thats quite longer than the original non javascript version isn't it? :)

Answer (score 0):

`$('#iframeId').contents().html();` should work, it seems.

See: http://api.jquery.com/contents/

edit: actually, I ran the following code on the above site and it works:

`var s = $('iframe:first').contents().find('*').html()`

Comment: thanks but was not similar to mootools. Sorry should have clarified!

Comment: Poster asked for MooTools not jQuery.

Comment: @LeeGee I appreciate the downvote and explanation, but if you look at the edits on the original question, it was originally tagged with jQuery and modified 6 hours after my post.  Originally, my answer was a response to the question of how to do it in mootools **or** jQuery: `how do i minify this. (mootools, but it probably looks similar in jQuery)`